# Sending the Debug Log to a Screen in an Android App

Tags: c#, android, debugging, unity-game-engine, logcat

While building an app, i have been getting problems getting the advertisements to display once the app is compiled and run on an android device. The biggest problem is with testing where the error is, since I can't access my debug log while on my android device.

So here is my question: Is there an existing function or plugin I can use to print the debug log to the bottom of the screen on my device? Or will I need to create one myself?

Note: If I end up writing one up first, I'll post my code as an answer for everyone else. If any one has some code that they use in their own programs, i invite them to post it here.

Comment: here is a Fabric crash analytics: http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk-android/ you will get crash reports in your mail

Comment: see my comment. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

set permission in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

and use this code to get log cat

```
public String getLogCat() {
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    String logCat = "";

    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", "-d", "-s", "-v", "time", "*:w" });
        reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            logCat += line;
        }
        in.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logCat = "";
    }

    return logCat;
}
```

**now, call this method in you code..**

```
String logCat = getLogCat();
```

Comment: I'm getting errors for `BufferedReader`. Is there a `using ...` line i need to be able to use it?

Comment: Actually, i'm getting errors for `InputStreamReader`, `Process`, `Runtime`, `BufferedReader`, `String`, and `IOException`.

Comment: you need open your android manifest and set permission..... <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

Comment: I did. I'm getting these errors within MonoDevelop. The error states: "error CS0103: The name \`InputStreamReader' does not exist int he current context"

Comment: What libraries are these functions part of? I'm using `UnityEngine`, `System.Collections`, and `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: I can't use the Process, InputStreamReader, BufferedReader, and String methods, since they arn't part of any of the libraries i am using. Unless you tell me which libraries i need to enable, i can't use them. So right now, no it is not working.